# GeoCouch / Couchdb / Other as searchable document-oriented db?

Tags: couchdb, geospatial, document-oriented-db

I would like to use a document oriented db to store data from a feed. Sometimes that feed contains Geo-spacial data and I would like to be able to search on it. I've found GeoCouch but wonder if it keeps up to date with the CouchDb mainline's features.

If GeoCouch is a one-off then is there a better Document Oriented DB out there that has Geo-spacial capabilities baked in ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also MongoDB supports spatial queries, but I'm happy with GeoCouch so far. Given the fact that Volker, the developer of GeoCouch is now hired by CouchOne, the future of GeoCouch might be assured. He's currently working on gc-separate, an "addon-like" branch that allows to add GeoCouch code over general CouchDB sources.

Also have a look at his roadmap: https://github.com/vmx/couchdb/wiki/Roadmap

Answer (score 2):

Just an update for future searchers: GeoCouch is no longer a fork of couchdb, but an extension:

https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch